# uploading project database to jazzhub

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, database-connection, project

I'm working on a small project with my team. Our job requires database, so I created one using mysql workbench 5.6 and succsesfully connected it to Netbeans 8.0. I was able to push and pull code to remote repository but not the database. My question is how to upload my database to remote repository (Jazzhub), so that everyone can pull it and can see it in his tab services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "upload database"?

Comment: I don't really know but maybe migration(making it online so that other members of the team can pull it.

Comment: You're going to have to qualify what you're looking for more specifically here. Why can't you just sling a `mysqldump` database snapshot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using version control (GIT) on a MySQL Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608706/using-version-control-git-on-a-mysql-database)

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608706/using-version-control-git-on-a-mysql-database , which provides a pretty good explanation on how to source control a database + possible pitfalls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating sql script in the project folder