# MySQL & GIT - Is it possible to use GIT versioning to merge MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git

**My problem is this:**

I am using MAMP to update many aspects of a WordPress site locally on my machine. Any change I make to a plug-in setting or any page/post attribute (not least of all, overhauling the homepage, or creating a new one) will update - for example - the `wp_posts` db table.

Meanwhile, a collaborator is busy generating content for the website in real time - updating existing posts or making new ones - also changing the `wp_posts` table and others.

If I upload the new db from my local machine to make it live, any work the collaborator has done is overwritten.

**My proposed solution is this:**

Put the primary ('live') db under version control (git in my case) as a remote (`origin`) so that I can push local changes and **merge** them with the `origin` database, using `git push origin master` instead of overwriting it.

I believe the number of merge conflicts would be minimal.

**My Question**

Is my proposed solution possible? Or some variation at least?

Comment: In particular, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17321646/2594812  is an answer that seems to answer your question

Comment: Thank you @SamHartman but I've gone through that answer as well as linked articles and there is nothing specifically about **merging**. I will update my question..

Comment: Oh, and is there an appeal process for the 'duplicate' tag? I don't agree that it is a dupe, and I don't want to miss out on any potential answers...

Comment: If you edit your question, it will get reviewed through the reopen queue.  I reviewed your question after your most recent edit and did not think the edit justifies a reopen vote.

Comment: Very good - thank you for the explanation! Plainly new around here.