# Modifying the "settings" of the MySQL stored procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-mode

According to the MySQL documentation, stored procedures are executed with the `sql_mode` in which they were created.

I need to change the sql_mode parameter for a specific stored procedure

`SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` command - shows the current sql_mode
`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

How can it be changed, specifically - remove strict mode

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to export the procedure's definition, then `DROP PROCEDURE` and then re-create it with `CREATE PROCEDURE` under the correct `sql_mode`.

Comment: Thank you Dai
it looks like this is the only way

Comment: @Dai You should post that as an answer, otherwise this question will stay in the "unanswered" queue forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Export the procedure's definition [with `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-procedure.html).

   - Save it to a `.sql` file on-disk for safe-keeping and ensure it matches the procedure in your project's source-control (git, SVN, TFS, etc).

     - ...and you *are* [using source-control for your database project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608706/using-version-control-git-on-a-mysql-database), right?
2. Then `DROP PROCEDURE`.
3. Then create a new MySQL session and [ensure `sql_mode` is set correctly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting).
4. Then `CREATE PROCEDURE` with the `.sql` file you saved in step 1.